# Deliver OfficeJS web addin wrapped in an VSTO addin

Tags: excel, office365, vsto, office-js, office-addins

I have an OfficeJS Excel add-in that I want to deploy in an environment, where neither centralized deployments, nor a SharePoint catalog is available for distribution.

Loading the add-in via a shared network drive works, but according to the microsoft docs this is not an option for a production deployment.

Other add-ins in that environment are all VSTO based.
Now my question is, if it's somehow possible to deliver the web-based add-in via a VSTO wrapper?

Would it alternatively be possible to provide the manifest on the the local drive for each user somehow?

EDIT:
Just to make it clearer - still want to serve the web-app via a server. I basically only want to distribute the manifest differently.

Comment: This blog post describes a deployment method that some people find helpful: https://theofficecontext.com/2020/03/23/web-add-in-side-loader-tool/

Answer (score 1):

> Loading the add-in via a shared network drive works, but according to the microsoft docs this is not an option for a production deployment.

When production options are not available, all other possible ways are good.

> my question is, if it's somehow possible to deliver the web-based add-in via a VSTO wrapper?

To deliver the manifest is not enough, so you need to sideload the add-in by adding the manifest file to the Office application. Isn't better to provide URL to the network share where manifest resides to users? VSTO is useless in that scenario. `OfficeJS` (not Excel) doesn't provide any API for loading web add-ins programmatically.

> Would it alternatively be possible to provide the manifest on the the local drive for each user somehow?

There is no need to keep the manifest on the local drive. You can provide URL of the manifest to sideload the add-in if the centralized deployment is not available (via the Office365 admin center).

Read more about possible routes in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.

Comment: Thx for your reply!

I see two major issues with the sideload approach:
1) Only one trust catalog can be active for the user at a time, so this approach does not scale if more than 1 network drive location is used for providing add-ins to the user

2) Excel somehow keeps a reference to the Add-In source in the document, so should the network path ever change, all documents that have been created with the add-in will not work anymore, even if the identical add-in is available on a different network path

Comment: Sorry, I misread something in your response - I thought you were only suggesting the network share. So you say that a URL to the manifest is sufficient. How would that add-in be loaded in Excel then? Is this something that can be automated like a setting in the registry?